# Guzzle 6 Basic Authentication continue with Session Cookie not working

Tags: curl, cookies, session-cookies, basic-authentication, guzzle

With Curl i authenticate to the server, get the session cookie written to file (cookies) and use it on the next request.

`curl --basic --digest --user restuser:restpassword --cookie-jar cookies --insecure https://xxx.example.dom/api/authentication`

Copy session_id cookie value from cookies file and use it:

`curl --cookie session_id=910f5e79aaf44dd8dc3c26e79e6d08bb22a86674 --insecure https://xxx.example.dom/api/configuration`

I wanted to implement this with Guzzle 6.1.1. It passes the basic authentication get the session cookie but do not pass it to the next request.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SessionCookieJar;
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SessionCookieJar('session_id', true);
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => REST_URL, 
    'cookies' => $jar, 
    'debug' => true
]);

// authenticate
$res = $client->request('GET', 'authentication', [
  'verify' => false,
  'auth' => [REST_USER, REST_PASS]
]);

// send authenticated request
$res = $client->request('GET', 'configuration', [
  'verify' => false
]);
```

In my understanding from the documentation, by setting persistent session cookies and using it while creating client, Guzzle should send them automagically within the next request am i wrong?

Thanks.

Note: Here is the debug output.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 129
Content-Language: en
Server: REST
Allow: DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT
Date: Sun, 07 Feb 2016 03:53:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: session_id=488df4282feb714f3fd2e36a1bb02ea06f923eb8; expires=Sun, 07 Feb 2016 04:13:02 GMT; httponly; Path=/; secure

* Connection #0 to host xxx.example.dom left intact
200Array{
    "_meta": {
        "href": "/api/authentication",
        "next": "/api",
        "transaction": "/api/transaction"
    }
}
* Found bundle for host xxx.example.dom: 0x100c18510
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host xxx.example.dom
* Connected to xxx.example.dom (192.168.68.100) port 443 (#0)
> GET /api/configuration HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.1.1 curl/7.41.0 PHP/5.6.7
Host: xxx.example.dom

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 284
Content-Language: en
Server: REST
Allow: DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT
Date: Sun, 07 Feb 2016 03:53:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: session_id=d1c231b1a093a1d9a9041597b3d708d32203e3f0; expires=Sun, 07 Feb 2016 04:13:02 GMT; httponly; Path=/; secure

* Connection #0 to host xxx.example.dom left intact

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `GET https://xxx.example.dom/api/configuration` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
```

Comment: looks like the session_id is different. is this the same client?